# react native firebase storage upload aborts on app close

Tags: firebase, react-native, file-upload, blob, firebase-storage

I have this function which uploads images to firebase storage. Normally it works, but when a user closes the app while ref.put(blob) is called the functions aborts and the image will not upload. Is there some way to continue this function in the background in case the app gets closed?

```js
export const uploadImage = (uri) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const ref = storage
        .ref()
        .child(//path);

          fetch(uri)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.blob();
            })
            .then((blob) => {
                return ref.put(blob);
            })
            .then(() => {
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            })
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firebase for continuing uploads in the background. Since you tagged with `react-native`, you can consider using something like [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task) to perform the entire upload in the background.